# django celery queue routing won't work

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, djcelery

I have two tasks. the task "heavy_task" need a concurrency of 1 and the "lite_task" need a concurrency of 4

```
@task
def lite_task():
    tabla = Proc_Carga()
    sp = tabla.carga()
    return None

@task()
def heavy_task(idprov,pfecha):
    conci = Buscar_Conci()
    spconc = conci.buscarcon(idprov,pfecha)
    return None
```

I define the routes in my settings.py file:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("pc.tasks", )
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.cache:CacheBackend'
CELERY_ROUTES = {"tasks.heavy_task": {"queue": "heavy"},"tasks.lite_task": {"queue": "lite"}}
```

I try to excute two workers specifying the concurrency in this way

```
celery multi start heavy lite -A provcon  -c:heavy 1 -c:lite 3
```

When first call the tasks heavy_task work fine and the concurrency works,
but after call the task lite_task the concurency for the queue heavy change.

I try this:

```
celery -A provcon worker -Q heavy -c 1
```

And when I execute the task heavy_task, the routing won't work and the task is not executed.

but if use this:

```
celery -A provcon -c 1
```

everything works fine, but I can only execute one task at time, and I need to be able to execute the heavy_task with a concurrency of 1 and the lite_task with a concurrency of 3

Any advice

Answer (score 0):

I try different settings to make the queues works and finally I did it.
In the tasks.py file I harcoded the the queue in the task decorator

```
@task(queue = 'heavy')
```

To run the workers I use this:

```
celery multi start lite_w heavy_w -A provcon -Q:heavy_w heavy -Q:carga_w lite -l info -c:heavy_w 1 -c:lite_w 3 -E
```

And i delete the routing settings from the settings.py file. My settings are this:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("pc.tasks", )
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.cache:CacheBackend'
```